# Opening custom objects

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classnotfoundexception, objectinputstream

I'm trying to open a custom class object in android studio. I created the file in a separate Java program using ObjectOutputStream, saved it as a .bin file and added it to the assets folder. I know the file can be opened as I have a separate desktop java app that can open and parse the data.

In Android Studio I've added the custom class ('TransferFile') to the same directory as MainActivity, and have tried the following code to open it:

```
    AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    TransferFile newTransfer = null;
    try {
        is = am.open("appendix.bin");
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        newTransfer = (TransferFile) objIn.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However I get the following ClassNotFound exception (truncated):

```
    04-20 11:46:44.618 11790-11790/? W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TransferFile
    04-20 11:46:44.618 11790-11790/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    04-20 11:46:44.618 11790-11790/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
    04-20 11:46:44.618 11790-11790/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
    04-20 11:46:44.618 11790-11790/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    04-20 11:46:44.618 11790-11790/? W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
```

In locating the issue, I believe it comes up when attempting to cast the object to the custom class.

Comment: I assume this is because android doesn't use java class files. It uses dex or art files. This seems like a super bad idea anyway.

Comment: Just for anyone visiting this page in the future: instead of directly trying to open the serialised object, I used XML to transfer the data. I used DocumentBuilder to create it from the first program, and XMLPullParser to read it in the second program.